# Proving: If $|x-y|<\frac{1}{n}$ for every natural $n$ then $x=y$

Tags: calculus

It's really basic but I am trying to prove:
$$
\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}.(\forall n\in \mathbb{N}. |x-y| <\frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow 
x=y)$$

I tried to prove it by proving that that if $$A= \left\{ \frac{1}{n} \ \middle| \ n\in\mathbb{N} \right\}$$
then the $$\operatorname{inf}(A) =0$$ but I couldn't find a way to use this after I proved it.
Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use limits here.

Comment: Hint. $-\dfrac1n+y<x<\dfrac1n+y$.

Comment: You can try by contradiction and then use the Archimedian property of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You should trust your opening sentence. If the LHS is non-zero then it is positive and call it $z$. Now $1/z$ is positive and just take the integer $n$ greater than it and you get a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x\neq y$, then
$$\vert{x-y}\vert>0$$
by **the Archimedian property of $\mathbb{R}$** there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$n\vert{x-y}\vert>z,\quad \forall z\in\mathbb{R}\ \text{with}\ z>0$$
take in particular $z=1$, 
so there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$m\vert{x-y}\vert>1$$
which gives
$$\vert{x-y}\vert>\frac{1}{m}$$
this is a contradiction.

Comment: It’s a bit confusing that you use the variable $y$ in this argument, when $y$ is already taken.

Comment: Exactly, call it $z$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\ne y$ then $|x-y|=d>0$

As $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$, then for any given $d>0$ there exists an index $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x-y|<\dfrac{1}{n}<d$.

This is a contradiction. Therefore must be $x=y$.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be any two distinct real numbers with $y \lt x$. Then, there exist rational numbers $p$ and $q$ satisfying $y \lt p \lt q \lt x$. If $n$ is a common denominator for $p$ and $q$, then $|q - p| \ge 1/n$. But then of course  $|x - y| \ge 1/n$.

Comment: I would have chosen $x<y$ :) :) this appears to be the simplest proof which shows that the problem is at a much lower level (suitable for 12 year olds) but thanks to modern textbooks it is usually given in a course meant for real analysis. +1

Comment: I wanted it to be easy calculating $|x-y|$ while matching up with the OP's question. I actually revised my answer - started out with $x \lt y$.  I also neglected to mention the "without loss of generality" thing - it doesn't matter what you assume. lol

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: 0 \leq |x-y| < \frac{1}{n}$$

The squeeze theorem yields that $|x-y| = 0$, or equivalently $x = y$

EDIT: I just saw you couldn't use limits. I'll leave this answer up anyway ,as it might help others interested in the same question.

Comment: How you can define $|x-y|$ as a sequence ?

Comment: @S.H.W $n\mapsto |x-y|$

Comment: Since x,y are chosen numbers, their difference is a constant number, so just the constant sequence $$(|x-y|)_n$$

Answer (score 0):

$z:=x-y;$ $x,y$ real.

$0 \le |z| \lt 1/n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

Every $1/n$, $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, is an upper bound for $|z|$.

$A:= ${$1/n$, $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$}.

$\inf (A):= 0;$

$\rightarrow:$

$0 \le |z| \le \inf (A) =0.$

Hence $z = 0$.

We prove that $\inf (A)  =0.$

$0$ is a lower bound for $A$:

Assume there is a lower bound  $L$, real,  of $A$ with $L>0$, I.e

$0 \lt L \le 1/n , n \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

There is a $ n_0  > 1/L .$
(Archimedes).

Then :  $0< 1/n_0 < L.$

Contradiction ,

hence $\inf(A) =0.$

Comment: That's what I tried to do but couldn't conclude |z|<inf(A)